# $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2 \ge 3(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a)$

Tags: inequality

Let: $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$, prove that: $$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2 \ge 3(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a)$$

This is my try:

Suppose: $a \leq b \leq c$, so put: $b=a+x$;$c=a+y$ $(x,y \geq 0$)

Then let:

$LHS-RHS = (x^2+y^2-xy)a^2 + (x^3+y^3+4xy^2-5x^2y)a+(x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2-3x^3y)$

So put: $f(a)=(x^2+y^2-xy)a^2 + (x^3+y^3+4xy^2-5x^2y)a+(x^4+y^4+2x^2y^2-3x^3y)$

And $\Delta_a=-3(x^3-x^2y-2xy^2-y^3)^2 \leq 0$, so the problem was solved.

Is there any solution simple than this solution, I want to make a short and natural solution. Thanks for all your helps!!

Comment: This is a well known inequality by Vasile Cirtoaje. Note that $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-3(a^3b+b^3c+c^3a)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(a^2-b^2-ab-ac+2bc)^2$

Comment: that's not a natural solution:(

Comment: @LụcTrườngPhát You should suppose $a = \min(a,b,c)$ rather than $a \le b \le c$ (since the inequality is not symmetric but cyclic).